# Does VS2013 use VS2015 Code Metrics Powertool?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, code-metrics

I installed the download for the Code Metrics Powertool for VS2013 and installed it. Metrics.exe was created in ...\12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FXCop. I downloaded and installed the Code Metrics Powertool for VS2015 and installed it. The VS2013 version disappeared and the VS2015 version showed up in ...\14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FXCop. It appears I can still calculate Code Metrics in VS2013. Is it using the VS2015 version? I can't find anything in the docs that indicates this happens and it's not the pattern for FXCop...

Comment: You can still use NDepend to compute .NET code metrics, that works with both VS2013 and VS2015   http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics